# Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V SAN Configuration

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, iscsi, hyper-v-server-2012

Struggling with what I thought would be a pretty easy setup and can't really see where I am going wrong. I have 2 Dell Hyper-V hosts running Server 2012 R2 connected to a Dell MD3800 SAN via 2 Netgear 10 GB switches.

One The SAN I Have:

> Created 3 LUNS
>   Created a hosts group and added both my hosts to it
>   Assigned the LUNs to the host group
>   Assigned IP addresses to my 2 RAID cards

One The Server Side:

> Installed iSCSI and MPIO
>   Installed Dell's driver set
>   Added the SAN

Within iSCSI and devices I can see my LUNS but the OS only ever brings through one lUN. The one it brings through behaves as if it was a single disk so both hosts will see it but cannot see data each server has written. I have configures the LUNS as MPIO on both servers. What's going on please?

Comment: `Within iSCSI and devices I can see my LUNS but the OS only ever brings through one lUN` - What do you mean exactly? Where are you seeing this? `The one it brings through behaves as if it was a single disk so both hosts will see it but cannot see data each server has written` - Of course, because it is a single disk. Each server shouldn't be directly writing to it simultaneously. You need to configure it as a Cluster Shared Volume for use with Hyper-V and Failover Clustering.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're planning to do sort of a failover cluster with a pass-thru disks (and you're unlikely...) you need to wrap a Cluster Shared Volume (CSV) on top of your shared LUN.

[Use Cluster Shared Volumes in a Failover Cluster](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868(v=ws.11).aspx)

If will give you a ClusterStorage combined block/SMB3 share where you'll host all of your VM VHDX files.

Comment: yeah, CSV is the way to go here. Pass-through disks are not recommended (issues with the failover and migration). it is going to be one of your headaches IMHO.